# i got sql syntax error when i debug my application

Tags: sql, vb.net

I want to update my database using formatsqlparam, but when I debug it, it has an error saying:

"Incorrect syntax near ','."

This is my code:

```
    Dim sql2 As String = "update infoHotel set nameHotel = N" & FormatSqlParam(hotel) & _
                                                       ", knownAs1 = N" & FormatSqlParam(KnownAs(0)) & _
                                                       ", knownAs2 = N" & FormatSqlParam(KnownAs(1)) & _
                                                       ", knownAs3 = N" & FormatSqlParam(KnownAs(2)) & _
                                                       ", knownAs4 = N" & FormatSqlParam(KnownAs(3)) & _
                                                       ", streetAddress = N" & FormatSqlParam(StreetAddress) & _
                                                       ", locality = N" & FormatSqlParam(Locality) & _
                                                       ", postalCode = N" & FormatSqlParam(PostalCode) & _
                                                       ", country = N" & FormatSqlParam(Country) & _
                                                       ", addressFull = N" & FormatSqlParam(address) & _
                                                       ", tel = N" & FormatSqlParam(contact) & ","

    Dim objCommand3 As New SqlCommand(sql2, conn)
    objCommand3.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Maybe I am missing some syntax, but I couldn't find where it is. I hope somebody can help. Thanks in advance. I'm using VB.Net and SQL.

Comment: This has already been answered, however you may find it useful in future to either get the value of sql2 from the debugger or even log the statements.  When you do that the sql should be easier to scan for errors, or even pasted into an sql shell in the hope it gives you a better errors message.

Answer (score 4):

The last line should be like this:

```
", tel = N" & FormatSqlParam(contact)
```

Also, you don't have a `Where` clause in your statement so this will update all rows in your table.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the trailing comma is your problem:

", tel = N" & FormatSqlParam(contact) & ","